# Sentence stress and word linking with the problematic Y?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, stress

the question: Can I use your bathroom? phonetically looks like: [kə_naɪ ˈyuz yər ˈbæθˌrum]

1. I think the stress should be on the verb USE and the noun BATHROOM.  Am I right?
2. Some dictionaries show the reduced form of "your" as /yər/ and some show it as /jər/.
   As far as I know /y/ can be both consonant and a vowel. If I decide to use /y/ in "your" as a vowel I can link the two words "USE + YOUR" together [ˈyu_zyər] because "z" is a consonant, but If I decide to use /jər/ with /j/, [ˈyuz jər] can't be linked together because there are two consonants.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could stress any word in that sentence and arrive at a different implied meaning.

Comment: But according to phonetic rules content words (nouns, verbs, adverbs) are more important than function words (preposition, pronouns, etc...) and the auxiliary verb (can) is not the main verb. It's just a helping verb.

Comment: Compare "Can I use **your** bathroom?" with "**Can** I use your bathroom?" Do you not see a difference in implication there?

Comment: Although it's always true that any word can be stressed to give it emphasis, there is a default unemphatic accent.

Comment: /j/is just a different symbol for /y/; /zyər/ and /zjər/ are identical, and both will palatalize to /ʒər/. You're right about the basic stress positions.

Comment: Following on from what Zoltan says, the *default* emphasis varies between US and British, I think.  I'd [Brit] say /ˈkan ɑɪ ˈjuːz jeɹ 'baθruːm/ [possibly dropping the first /ɹ/]. I *think* [please correct me] that most Americans would say /kən ˈɑɪ juːz jəɹ ˈbæθruːm/.  This is apart from any palatization, which I might do speaking quickly.